# Sorting list after Date then time

Tags: c#, linq, sorting, datetime

So I'm working on a website ( MVC ) that handles Schedule entries for bands during a festival and I need to present bookings in a logical order and I´m having some unexpected difficulties when I try to order them. My goal is to order them first by date and then by time.

I've  obviously read all similar questions that I could find but none seems to solve the problem.

This is my model (The parts that matter in this situation):

```
public int ScheduleEntryId { get; set; }
public int ScheduleId { get; set; }
public int? BandId { get; set; }
public int? MovieId { get; set; }
public int? TechnicianId { get; set; }
public DateTime? StartTime { get; set; }
public DateTime? EndTime { get; set; }
public DateTime EventDate { get; set; }
```

I´m trying to get a sorted list of entries from a specific Band. So this is what I have at the moment:

```
List<ScheduleEntry> scheduleEntries =
    db.ScheduleEntries.Where(x => x.BandId == band.BandId)
        .OrderBy(x => x.EventDate)
        .ThenBy(z => z.StartTime.Value).ToList();
```

This does sort the entries after the date, but not after time.

I have also tried to seperate the linq and sorting so that I can use .TimeOfDay, since linq does not support that method. This is what I tried:

```
var scheduleEntries = db.ScheduleEntries.Where(x => x.BandId == band.BandId).ToList();
scheduleEntries.OrderByDescending(z => z.EventDate.Date).ThenBy(z=> z.StartTime.Value.TimeOfDay);
```

I know this is pretty silly and I´m probably missing something obvious, but I just cant get it to work properly. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does the `EventDate` contain a time of day? If it does it is likely to provide a complete ordering without considering a second sort field.

Comment: I don't understand the issue, sorting by a DateTime (assuming it is actually a DateTime and contains both date and time) would accomplish a sort "by date, then time"

Comment: Assuming that `StartTime` does contain the correct _date_ (the one stored in `EventDate` you may try to _only_ sort by `StartTime` and not by `EventDate` in the first place.

Comment: I'm only guessing based on your object, but is `EventDate` only the date portion?  How could `StartTime` be nullable?  Couldn't you combine the two properties so that you simply have a `EventStartDateTime` and `EventEndDateTime`?  Shouldn't enddatestimes be required?  If you're using start and end as only the time portion, what happens if an event bleeds over past midnight?  Or is multiple days long?

Comment: @Richard The eventdate contains a full datetime value, but the time aspect will always be set to 00.00.00.

Comment: @RenéVogt Tried scheduleEntries.OrderByDescending(z => z.StartTime.Value.Day).ThenBy(z => z.StartTime.Value.TimeOfDay); 

Does not seem to work either. 

Kritner Yes I agree, but I did not set up the database structure so this is basically what I have to work with.

Comment: So to make things abit clearer the thought was that Eventdate just holds the actual date while start and endtime only holds the relevant times. I agree that @Kritner proposal makes alot more sense, but in this instance I can't really change it unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
List<ScheduleEntry> scheduleEntries = db.ScheduleEntries
  .Where(x => x.BandId == band.BandId)
  .OrderBy(x => x.EventDate)
  .ThenBy(z => z.StartTime)
  .ToList();
```

Edited As per @IvanStoev's suggestion in the comments

Comment: Unfortunately this results in the following error:

Additional information: The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.

Comment: If you run this SQL query manually (e.g. in SQL Management Studio), do you get the correct result? `select * from Schedule where BandId = 1 order by EventDate, StartTime`

Comment: Can you just use `x.EventDate`?

Comment: @Jocie Yes I do get the correct order if I run the query in SQL management studio!

Comment: @Lasselito Then `.OrderBy(x => x.EventDate).ThenBy(x => x.StartTime)` should also work. Have you checked the generated SQL?

Comment: @IvanStoev I cannot for the life of me understand why I didnt just try this the first time around. Because this works! I always try to be more specific than necessary.

Thank you alot Ivan and everybody else that helped out!